# How to sort a list of colours and assign it to four categories?

Tags: color, sorting

I have a list of colours with RGB values like this :

```
colours= {{0.943191, 0.90752, 0.892025, 1.}, {0.966108, 0.937493, 0.95011, 
  0.970242}, {0.868674, 0.863689, 0.760482, 1.}, {0.794621, 0.69106, 
  0.0394653, 1.}, {0.284631, 0.266542, 0.238138, 0.999657}, {0.784956,
   0.752576, 0.610585, 1.}, {0.69756, 0.146182, 0.0920077, 
  1.}, {0.65915, 0.632454, 0.659941, 0.996078}}
```

I want to assign these to four colours: white, yellow, orange, black. How do I do this in Mathematica?. My ideal output would be a list like {white, white, white..yellow, orange}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
nearestColor[clist_] := Map[First @ Nearest[clist][RGBColor@#] &]
```

***Examples:***

```
nearestColor[{White, Yellow, Orange, Black}] @ colours
```

[image]

[Nearest > Details and Options:](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html)

[image]

```
nearestColor[ColorData[97] /@ Range[3]]@colours
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works very well!

Comment: @dinesh, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
colours = {{0.943191, 0.90752, 0.892025, 1.}, {0.966108, 0.937493, 
    0.95011, 0.970242}, {0.868674, 0.863689, 0.760482, 1.}, {0.794621,
     0.69106, 0.0394653, 1.}, {0.284631, 0.266542, 0.238138, 
    0.999657}, {0.784956, 0.752576, 0.610585, 1.}, {0.69756, 0.146182,
     0.0920077, 1.}, {0.65915, 0.632454, 0.659941, 0.996078}};
refs = {White, Yellow, Orange, Black};
cols = RGBColor @@@ colours;
pos = Flatten[#, 
    1] &@(Position[#, Min@#] & /@ (ColorDistance[#, refs] & /@ cols))

Grid[{cols, Extract[refs, pos]}]
```

With `v13.2` you can replace the mechanics for `pos` above with [PositionSmallest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionSmallest.html.en?view=all&source=footer).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've learnt a couple of new things with your approach